# Real unipolar neurons do indeed exist in human?

Tags: neuroscience, neuroanatomy

I studied that the unipolar neuron in human body are not really unipolar but they're **pseoudounipolar** neurons. On the other hand according to what I understood from wikipedia (neuron) there are **real** **unipolar neuron**.

In fact, I'm confused (if unipolar cell does exist in human body or doesn't) and I would like get you help about it.